# Operation on ArrayList elements without using any loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am writing one java program in which I don't want to use any loop for array list elements.
Sure below program will print the output from 0 to n without using any loop because ArrayList inherits a toString() method with a loop in it from AbstractCollection.

```
import java.util.*;
class withoutloop{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    arr.add(i);
    System.out.println(arr);
}
}
```

But I want to put some calculations using each element in array list without any loop.Like the below program

```
import java.util.*;
class withoutloop{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int m = scan.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    arr.add(i);
    for(int i=2;i<=m;i++){
    Iterator it = arr.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Integer element = it.next();
            if(element%i==0)
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
}
```

Now if I use this program this will give me approximately O(n*m) solution which I don't want. Is there any way I can access all elements in array list without using any loop ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It looks like your code tells whether any numbers in `[0..N]` are factors of any numbers in `[2..M]` (which will be `true` for any N and M both >= 2).

Comment: @4castle Yea and I have those numbers 0 to n in an array list. And I don't want to use another loop for array list.

Comment: What I'm saying is, your program can be reduced to `System.out.println(n >= 2 && m >= 2);`

Comment: @4castle I didn't understand. Can you elaborate it ?

Comment: What question does your code try to answer? What is the purpose of the program? You don't even need an array or arraylist to get the output your program has. You can have an O(1) solution.

Comment: @4castle Let's say I have two number n and m which I want to find that whether any number of n range 0 to n is module of m ranging 2  to m or not. Even If I don't use arraylist I have to run the nested two for loops right?

Comment: There's no need for any loops, because `2 % 2 == 0`, so there's no need to evaluate if n and m are both at least 2.

Comment: @4castle but let's say I want to count the number of module ?

Comment: Then you will have to use a loop of some kind. Are you asking if there is a simpler syntax for your code?

Comment: In the first code snippent you state. _Sure below program will print the output from 0 to n without using any loop because ArrayList inherits a toString() method with a loop in it from AbstractCollection._ No it uses a for loop to do that: `for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)`

Comment: I question what you mean by: _But I want to put some calculations using each element in array list without any loop._ Both posted code snippets use 1 or more for loops. I am curious how you would access each element in the array without one, even with an iterator. Yes you can make a line for each element in the array: arry[0] = value1, arry[1] = value2, arry[2] = value3, it will work… but it’s a waste of time and it creates future problems if the array size changes. Again without a loop of some form… I would be interested to see this.

Comment: I just don't want to use two nested for loops. I understand there is no point of using array list. If there is a simpler syntax for this code then can you it show me ?

Comment: @JohnG Yea I know that it uses a for loop to do that. But my next question is if it uses a for loop to do that can I put some calculations in that loop by overriding the function like it uses it to print the arraylist so that I don't have to use it in my code?

Comment: You should take a closer look at 4castle's comments.

Comment: Yea I know using a loop of some kind...

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 can make your code simpler using [`IntStream.rangeClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-), but there is little you can do to avoid having an O(n*m) solution without devising a smarter algorithm.

```
long count = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n)
                      .mapToLong(element -> IntStream.rangeClosed(2, m)
                          .filter(i -> element % i == 0)
                          .count())
                      .sum();
System.out.println(count);
```

Previous to Java 8, the equivalent code would be something like:

```
long count = 0;
for (int element = 0; element <= n; element++) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
        if (element % i == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```